# Installing libv8 and therubyracer on Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gcc, therubyracer, libv8

I'm about to tear my hair out with trying to get `therubyracer` gem to install on Mavericks 10.9 - any help would be *immensely* appreciated.

I understand that there's a host of other questions about this subject, but literally none of the following (including various combinations and hopeful retrials which have consumed 2+ days at this point) have solved any issue

1. Uninstalling `libv8` and install `therubyracer`
2. Using `brew install libv8` instead
3. Installing `apple-gcc` or similar
4. Installing various versions of `Xcode` and `Developer Tools`
5. Reinstalling `rvm` and re-building `ruby 1.9.3`

The latest I've been able to achieve is to get this error message:

```
> gem install therubyracer
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/aqua/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150127-54061-10i2fna.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
compiling accessor.cc
g++-4.6: error: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
make: *** [accessor.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/aqua/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/aqua/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/1.9.1/therubyracer-0.12.1/gem_make.out
```

There doesn't seem to be much information around `g++-4.6: error: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'`. My first guess was maybe that `gcc46` does not support this flag.

Based on other post suggestions I tried installing `apple-gcc42`:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install apple-gcc42
```

And executed it again with the proper enviornment context variables to point it to the new `apple-gcc42` installation:

```
> $ CC=/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2 CPP=/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/cpp-4.2 CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/g++-4.2 gem install therubyracer
```

Still no luck, and it was oddly still throwing the same error about `gcc46`, which makes me thing that it's not picking up `apple-gcc42` *at all*

I even tried symlinking the correct versions (backing up the originals of course)

```
cd /usr/bin

mv gcc gcc_backup
mv g++ g++_backup
mv cpp cpp_backup

sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/g++-4.2 /usr/bin/g++
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/cpp-4.2 /usr/bin/cpp
```

Absolutely no luck, still throwing `g++-4.6: error: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'`

So.. **How do you force the `gem install` to use a specific compiler version? Is that even the right approach?**

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. Followed the same steps you have described above. Below are the additional exports I did to install therubyracer.

```
export CC=/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2
export CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/g++-4.2
export CPP=/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/cpp-4.2
```

I did not do *brew install libv8*

Next, uninstalled libv8 gem

```
gem uninstall libv8
```

Finally installed therubyracer

```
gem install therubyracer -v='0.12.2'
```

I am using ruby 2.2.2, hope this helps.